# Apache Tika: Where to place tika.xml to disable OCR

Tags: java, extract, ocr

I am running Apache Tika to extract text from a bunch of MS Office documents. My command looks like this:

`java -jar "c:\path\to\tika-app-2.0.0.jar" -t ...`

(I am running this command on Win10 in a MSYS2 terminal). Get a lot of messages like this:

`INFO  [main] 08:02:46,683 org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser Tesseract is installed and is being invoked. This can add greatly to processing time.  If you do not want tesseract to be applied to your files see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaOCR#TikaOCR-disable-ocr`

In which directory do I need to put the `tika.xml` that they give? I put it in `c:\path\to\` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the config file anywhere that you like.

Use the Environment Variable of `TIKA_CONFIG` to point to the file.

Reference:
[Configuring Tika - Using a Tika Configuration XML file](https://tika.apache.org/1.9/configuring.html#Using_a_Tika_Configuration_XML_file).